# smart pointer ( different between ~auto_ptr() and release() )

Tags: c++

I would like to know the different between the `~auto_ptr()` and `release()` functions.

Are they the same method, or are there differences between the destruction and the release of the memory?

Answer (score 8):

**auto_ptr::release()**

Sets the auto_ptr internal pointer to null pointer (which indicates it points to no object) without destructing the object currently pointed to by the auto_ptr.  It returns the value of the internal pointer before it was set to null.
After calling `release()` the `auto_ptr` can still be pointed to another object.

**auto_ptr::~auto_ptr()**

Deallocates the block of memory the object "points to" using delete and destructs the object.\After calling `~auto_ptr()` the `auto_ptr` is destroyed and should not be used further.

Answer (score 3):

Ehm... never call a destructor yourself, only if you allocated the space where the object resides with a placement new.
That said, the difference is, that `release` is valid and leaves the object in a valid state, with the possibility to accept another pointer.
`~auto_ptr` will destruct the object and leave it in an invalid state, using it after calling the destructor is undefined behaviour.